# Uploading images from a django application to a Google AppEngine application

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am not running Django on AppEngine. I just want to use AppEngine as a content delivery network, basically a place I can host and serve images for free. It's for a personal side project.

The situation is this: I have the URL of an image hosted on another server/provider. Instead of hotlinking to that image its better to save it on AppEngine and serve it from there - this applies mostly for thumbnails.

My questions are these:

- How do I authenticate from my Django app (let's say A) to my AppEngine app (B), so that only I can upload images
- How do I make a request from A to B saying "Fetch the image on this URL, create a thumbnail and save it."
- How do I tell B that "For this url return that image"
- How can I handle errors or timeouts? And how can this be done asynchronously?

Answer (score 1):

Afaik you can not store files in App Engine programmatically. You can just store them, when uploading your app.

You can however store information in its data store. So you would need to deploy an app, that authenticates your user and then writs the image to the gae's data store

Answer (score 1):

In my application, i use a third part server to upload a picture more than 1Mega into GAE.

So, for that; The formulaire posts all data into the third part server.
The server resizes the image and repost it to GAE.

I use a pattern iframe for the userfriendly.

The sourcecode is on github http://github.com/sahid/up2gae maybe you can you inspired by them.